# Add class to category Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, class, categories

I want to add a class to my css if a category is displayed but I can't get it to work.

I added this to my header:

if ( is_category('areas')) { echo ' class="myclass" '; }

I want to add this class to my stylesheet to any page in this category so It changes the look of any page in that category. It isn't working though.

Ive read through a lot of the codex and this is all I can figure to do

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where exactly are you putting this code? It needs to go inside an element (ie `<div>` or `<p>`) in order to style it.

Comment: So I've read through stuff on this site and still have no idea how to accept an answer.  there is nowhere on this page I see a button that says how to accept an answer.  Where is it??????

Comment: @user1155141 on the left of every answer to one of your questions is the gray outline of a hook. Click on that to accept an answer. The whole concept is actually described quite well in the faq page, songdogtech posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably easiest to up WP's bodyclass; that will put in all the body classes you will need. With

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

in header.php, it will output something like

```
<body class="archive category category-my-category-name category-1 logged-in">
```

The call that class in CSS, i.e.

```
body.category-my-category-name #my-div {background-color:#fff;}
```

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class